# Return HtmlString From Model & Display Within View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, mvchtmlstring

Let me preface this by saying that I know that I can use **HTML.Raw()** to display HTML contained in a string. However, I believe that the purpose of MVC is to separate the code logic and to allow front end developers to focus on UI and not logic. Therefore, I try to pass everything I can from the model exactly as I want it to look.

That brings me to my question. I have a model that contains an address. I have written a function that returns the address in a few different versions (single line, two line, multiline) and I'm setting these as **HtmlString** objects.

```
public HtmlString TwoLine { get { return ReturnFullAddress(2); } }
/* function removed for brevity */
```

However, when I write the following razor code:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address.TwoLine)
```

No text is returned within the view. When I debug this, there IS a value properly assigned within Address.TwoLine, but it is within { } (which I thought was strange).

How do I make this work, or why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DisplayFor()` doesn't know how to handle `HtmlString` properties.
You should just print the value directly: `@Model.Address.TwoLine`

Comment: `DisplayFor()` does not accept `HtmlString`. Changing my variable back to a string and using `DisplayFor()` results in nothing appearing. Using `Html.Raw` works still. Also, just a note... this is within a foreach loop.

Comment: @Eric: Don't use `DisplayFor` at all.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I meant `Display()`. However, after re-reading your reply, I now understand that you meant to literally just write `@Model.Address.TwoLine` without any `@Html.Display()`. This did work. However, it does drive me to ask... why EVER use `Display` or `DisplayFor`?

Comment: @Eric: `DisplayFor()` allows you to write your own display templates that turn aribtrary types into markup.  (which is probably what you should be doing here)

Comment: Any good resources for learning that? I'm new to MVC, so its been a huge gear change from web forms.